# .py python file displaying code instead of executing on webhost

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am trying to get a html page to take a text input and have a python script get it and print it out.  I had this working correctly while I was on a trial period for a webhost, and after I upgraded to a full account, I transferred the files over and it stopped working.  I might have missed a step in the setup, but I can't figure out where.  Here is what I did:

I set up a python virtualenv and then I activated it by going into SSH and typing in `source /home/username/virtualenv/test/3.5/bin/activate` and confirmed that it was activated.

Then I tried to run my index.html file that is in my public_html folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/hello.py" method="get">
        Enter Message: <input type="text" name="message">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything displayed correctly.  When I enter anything into the input box and click submit, it should execute my hello.py script that is in my cgi-bin folder:

```
#!/home/username/virtualenv/test/3.5/bin/python

import cgi

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print (data["message"].value)
```

All that displays is the actual python code, instead of the input from the html.

I tried it also with #!/usr/bin/python in the python script and it still displays just the python code.

Comment: Did you tell the server that it should be executing .py files?

Comment: I have given the correct 755 permissions but still can't get it to execute the .py file instead of just displaying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by creating a .htaccess file with the following rules in the cgi-bin folder:

`Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py`

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this, in hope of it proving helpful to you in future migration to another host or any similar situation. You need to know what happened in the background.

Also, consider ticking the tickmark (until it turns green) so that people will know this question is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

---

Basically, Apache needed to know that .py files are going to be executed as CGI Scripts. On a full VPS account, where you have root access, you would have needed to edit the apache configuration file (httpd.conf) or just added a .htaccess file as you did above.

On a shared hosting (which I assume you are using), where you don't have root access, only the second option would work (as it did).

Also, consider using the .cgi for your script instead of .py (Python would work the same) since that is the default handler for cgi-scripts on apache.